# Kubuntu freezes after leaving on login screen

Tags: kubuntu, freeze, login-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Sometimes after I logout (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and leave my pc for a night I can't wake it up next day.

It is happening randomly like 1-2 times per week. In the morning the screen is black and input from keyboard/mouse don't work (shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> or with <kbd>F1</kbd> don’t work too) so I have to restart system manually.

Any idea how to prevent it? (I use updated Kubuntu, doing updates ever time new is released)

Comment: After this recurs, reboot and go to /var/log and look at the last few syslogs (at the end of the files) for error messages and report them here.  The newest syslog will be for your current run, so will probably have no errors.  Just for good measure, run dmesg | less or redirect it into a file dmesg > ~/dmmesg.txt so you can look at that using less or a text editor and see if there are any non-fatal errors in your system that may be contributing to the fatal one later. If the logs aren't in /var/log, they may be somewhere under /run.  Distros are gradually switching things from /var to /run.

Comment: I don't have this problem (kubuntu 11.10), but I do occasionally get a black screen after I reopen my notebook/lid (set to do nothing except turn off the display when the lid is shut with external power applied.)  I have to do a hardware shutdown (hold the power button down until the firmware powers down the notebook) to get out of it.

Comment: It didn't happen for a month and now 2 night a row. I can't find anything useful in logs. Any other idea? I don't know why someone closed this topic since its different then simple freeze.